# pyvisa, function viOpen not found

Tags: python, pyvisa

When I run in 32 bit python,

```
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\latshaw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 3015, in **new**
> visa_library = open_visa_library(visa_library)
> File "C:\Users\latshaw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 2929, in open_visa_library
> return cls(argument)
> File "C:\Users\latshaw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 175, in **new**
> raise OSError("Could not open VISA library:\n" + "\n".join(errs))
> OSError: Could not open VISA library:
> function 'viOpen' not found

Here is what I have tried so far:
re-installed with pip

> $ pip install -U pyvisa

Here is some info of the install:

> python -m visa info

C:\Users\latshaw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\visa.py:13: FutureWarning: The visa module provided by PyVISA is being deprecated. You can replace `import visa` by `import pyvisa as visa` to achieve the same effect.
The reason for the deprecation is the possible conflict with the visa package provided by the https://github.com/visa-sdk/visa-python which can result in hard to debug situations.
warnings.warn

Machine Details:
Platform ID:    Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Processor:      Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel

Python:
Implementation: CPython
Executable:     C:\Users\latshaw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Version:        3.8.5
Compiler:       MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)
Bits:           32bit
Build:          Jul 20 2020 15:43:08 (#tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0)
Unicode:        UCS4

PyVISA Version: 1.11.3

Backends:
ivi:
Version: 1.11.3 (bundled with PyVISA)
#1: C:\windows\system32\visa32.dll:
found by: auto
bitness: 32
Could not get more info:
function 'viOpen' not found

I am not sure what is going wrong here. From my research, it seems that the biggest 2 ways that people make mistakes are in mismatching a 32 version of pyvisa and a 64 bit version of IDLE (both of mine are 32 bit) and the other is in naming the file visa.py (which I am not doing).

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I found that this is a problem for python 3.8 as it does not load the DLL files correctly (something about an environmental PATH). In my specific case, I am interested in loading the keysight visa, so the below works for me.

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Keysight\\IO Libraries Suite\\bin')
import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager('ktvisa32')
```

and now rm returns:

```
rm <enter>
<ResourceManager(<IVIVisaLibrary('ktvisa32')>)>
```

I think that this is the fix to my problem. However, I am running 'offline' right now and am not able to access the key-sight test equipment to see if I can talk to them over the python scripts. My fingers are crossed :)

Thanks for reading :)